# Well pump only works with on/off switch not control box

Tags: switch, sprinkler-system, multiway-switch, well-pump

My well pump is setup with an on/off switch that works fine as well as a control box that should be turning it on when activated.  Now it just makes a clicking sound and nothing happens.  I am attaching an image of the setup as well.  the [image: er] piece with the brown square moves out when the control box turns on and back when off.

Comment: With the power off, check underneath  the metal  rectangle piece to see if it's making contact with the  screw terminals below it.  That device it a control relay and it appears to be the problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be making contact with those screw terminals underneath it.  How would it normally do this? Through direct contact? seems like the brown plastic is in the way of there being any metal to metal contact there

Comment: It wouldn't be making contact with the screws but with some contacts further in and also some contacts on the bottom of that metal piece..

Comment: Thanks will check tomorrow when its light out again!

Answer (score 3):

The clicking is the relay being pulled in. This is a common failure in relays after thousands of cycles the contacts burn and do not make good contacts, I have special burnishing tools to clean the contacts and this can also be done with a fine sandpaper (400+ grit), but cutting away contact material is a short term fix in some cases. A new relay is going to be needed in most cases.
The part number is usually stamped on the body, or the voltage of the controller and the voltage & amperage of the relay will be needed to get a replacement.

I only see 4 wires, 2 are the control voltage that pull in the coil and the other 2 are the “switch” that sends power to the pump.  Make sure to label them, so you don’t mix them up.

Comment: Thank you sir!  Great advice.  I'd probably go with replacing this if thats a better long term fix.  Will research what to get here unless you have some suggestions.

Comment: Since the relay only has 2 contacts it is probably 120v 20 amp with the control coil being 120v but that is a guess I often do use relays to allow the load to be switched by the relay a relay is much cheaper than a new pressure switch, make sure to get a relay that is motor rated probably 1 hp or less.